# How do I solve this error to restore my old blog?

Tags: xml, templates, blogger

I am trying to restore my old template for my blog but when i do i try to I get this message:c

"We were unable to save your template.

Your template could not be parsed as it is not well-formed. Please make sure that all XML elements are closed properly. XML error message:
There should be one and only one skin in the template, and we found: 0"

I've read that there's a solution but can someone give me step by step instructions on how i correct this?

Comment: Is this programming-related? Do you have the XML in question? As written there may not be enough information here for you to get the help you need.

Comment: I was in blogger and I was trying to restore my old blog. I made sure I saved it because I was doing some editing and I thought i might need to go back. But this error showed up when I tried to upload it again. There's a lot of code in the xml file. I'm not sure what part of it or how much of it to post (sorry I'm not very good with this stuff). I did try putting it through W3 validator. It said the xml code WAS well-formed but it found 'no DOCTYPE'. I have no idea what any of this means.

Answer (score 2):

By deafualt Every blogger template needs to have the skin tag whether or not u put something in between the tags.Usually,CSS styles are included in those tags.

Simply go to head section of the template and paste this code and this shall resolve your error :)

```
 <b:skin><![CDATA[
]]></b:skin>
```

Answer (score 2):

To edit your own blogger templates or paste your own code in templates, you must have the following main section in blogger templates...

```
//header:
<b:section id="header-section" class="header-section" maxwidgets="1" showaddelement="no"></b:section>
//mainNav:
<b:section id="mainNav-section" class="mainNav-section" maxwidgets="1" showaddelement="no"></b:section>
//main .content:
<b:section id="content-section" class="content-section" showaddelement="yes"></b:section>
//sidebar:
<b:section id="sidebar-section" class="sidebar-section" showaddelement="yes">
</b:section>
//footer:
<b:section id="footer-section" class="footer-s"></b:section>
```